# Negative voltage regulator with up to 100 mA current

Tags: integrated-circuit, switching-regulator

I want to reverse a board and design a similar one. It is written on its negative regulator `eadrfo` (in some cases `eadrbc`). I used `LMC7660` as a negative voltage regulator for -3.3 volt, but because I need a current greater than 50mA the voltage of regulator(`LMC7660`) drops down to -2.1 volt.
Does someone knows which ICs are represented with `eadrbc` or `eadrfo`

Comment: If you wanted better help you should have posted a picture. That would have at least given an idea of the package size

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used from ~LM266x~ with 200mA output current

Answer (score 0):

you can use ADM660, it can deliver you up to 100mA output current, or you can use mc34063 with the below circuit for higher load current:
[image]

Comment: I used ~MC34063~ and I see its datasheet but this circuit give me 2.3v

Comment: mc34063 is obsolete